# How to use df.isnull() with if conditional statements in python(or necessary dataframe to use)

Tags: python, pandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

    
#opening the datasets
def load_data(file_name=None):
    """takes csv file as parameter and returns it exception is raised incase of error during opening of the file."""
    try:
        df=pd.read_csv(file_name)
        return df
    except Exception as e:
        raise "File open failed due to {} error".format(e)
    
#Identifying missing values
def missing_values(files):
    """Takes an iterable of file objects and returns true if there is a null value and false otherwise"""
    try:
        for i in files:
            with open(i) as f:
                f_ile=pd.DataFrame(load_data(f))
                if f_ile.isnull():
                    """Missing values were found return true"""
                    print("Missing values:\n{}".format(f_ile.isnull().sum()))
                    return True
                else:
                    """Missing values were not found in the dataset hence return false for each of the dataset."""
                    return False
    except Exception as e:
        print("{}".format(e))
```

How can I evaluate isnull() pandas method using if conditional statement. above code returns ValueError:truth value of the dataframe is ambgous. use a.empty, a.bool(), a.any() or a.all()

what are the necessary data conversions that i should make if none then what should I do.

Comment: df.isnull() does not return a boolean value. It returns a dataframe of same size of the original dataset, with True corresponding to null values. What do you wanna do exactly? Do you want to count null values in each dataframe?

Comment: The `except` in `load_data` is unnecessary. You could be losing useful trace info.

Comment: I want to find if there is any null value present, if so return the appropriate boolean in my custom function

Answer (score 0):

For data frames, isna() is regularly used to find NaNs. Use `f_ile.isna().sum() > 0` to check if there are any NaNs.

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: The same error I had earlier(pandas ambigous data frame error), it returns a data frame too. So I converted it to list to work with it pythonic way and my problem is solved right now I appreciate. You can suggest other ways though can still be helpful

Answer (score 0):

so I converted the data frame to list and evaluated if the total is greater than 0 to walk around my problem hope it helps. Meanwhile you can suggest the best option if that's not it. Here is the modified section of the code

```
#Identifying missing values
def missing_values(file):
    """Takes an iterable of file objects and returns true if there is a null value and false otherwise"""
    try:
        f_ile=pd.DataFrame(load_data(file))
        val=f_ile.isna().sum()
        mis_val_list=val.values.tolist()
        if sum(mis_val_list)>0:
            """Missing values were found return true"""
            print("Missing values:\n{}".format(f_ile.isna().sum()))
            return True
        else:
            """Missing values were not found in the dataset hence return false for each of the dataset."""
            print("No missing value:\n{}".format(f_ile.isnull().sum()))
            return False
    except Exception as e:
        #Shows the error captured
        print("{}".format(e))
```